# File Reader prints out "?" instead of file

Tags: java, filereader

Whenever I hit compile I get "?" as an output. No errors or anything, just the question mark.
Here's my code:

```java
import java.io.*;
    
public class FileReaderExample {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("path to my text file");
            int data = fileReader.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                data = fileReader.read();
            }
            System.out.print((char)data); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("There's been an error.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output as a picture? And also, do you want to print (char)data only one time?

Comment: `while (data != -1) {data = fileReader.read();}` this will keep overwriting `data` *before* printing it.

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos do you need a picture of a `?`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca well, i want a picture in case he is missing something. Everybody may gets confused. It may outputs a message that he thinks it's not necessary to post.

Comment: Well, it literally outputs just the question mark and nothing more, hence my confusion.

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos the problem seems pretty clear. They're only printing when `data` becomes `-1` (i.e. when the loop ends). I was wondering *why* you thought you needed further info.

Comment: You should print while you are reading . Not after all the file has been read.As @Henry pointed out -1 denotes the end of the file. and there are no characters corresponding to -1. Hence the ?.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's working properly now.

Comment: Why not use BufferedReader#readLine()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your program reaches `System.out.print((char)data);` the value of `data` is -1. This is not a printable character hence the `?`.